# Looking For Compiled Version of Metasploit Local Windows Exploits

Tags: exploit, metasploit

I am looking to have a standalone compiled exploits for all local windows exploits that Metasploit has right now. I was wondering if somebody has done this before or know a place that has these exploits as an executables that are ready to execute on the vulnerable system.

Here is a list of the exploits that I am looking for:
https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/tree/master/modules/exploits/windows/local

Comment: Hi Ahmed - your last three questions have been off topic. Please have a re-read of the [about] page to re-familiarise yourself with the types of questions that work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are going to find any.

The information such as the target, payload, etc *I believe* is compiled into executables which Metasploit serves up.

A precompiled binary would be useless for all practical purposes, besides maybe malware detection. Even then there are options for packers in Metasploit.